# How to compile a C file with an OpenSSL dependency?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, whatsapp

I'm trying to decrypt my whatsapp password using a tutorial, but got stuck at [the step for compiling `wa_pbkdf2.c`](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/Extracting-password-from-device#bash). I pasted the code at [Pastebin Untitled](http://pastebin.com/e2YKeE8d/).

I tried in on my Ubuntu laptop, but it said

```
Fatal Error: openssl/509.h No such file or directory
```

I have OpenSLL installed but somehow the compiler can't find it. Any ideas how to compile it?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here if you can.

Comment: That C# code looks and sounds suspiciously like C to me... You might want to swap the tag.

Comment: The amswer to *"Fatal Error: openssl/509.h No such file or directory"* is to install the developer packages. If you only install `openssl`, then you only get the binaries and shared objects. To get the headers like `openssl/509.h`, you need the dev package. It applies to other libraries as well.

Comment: @jww Are they still called openssl/509.h? Or something like openssl-dev/509.h?

Comment: @coolnickname - No, I believe OpenSSL calls it `<openssl/x509.h>`.